# tcpdf adds php multi line quotes at the end of the script

Tags: php, tcpdf

every pdf file that it generates, it keeps adding

```
/* */
```

right after last line of text. What can cause such a weird behavior? Here is my setup:

```
    $tcpdf = new TcPdf;
    $tcpdf->setPrintHeader(false);
    $tcpdf->setPrintFooter(false);
    $tcpdf ->setFontSubsetting(true);
    $tcpdf->AddPage();
    $tcpdf ->SetFont('freesans', '', 11);
    $tcpdf->writeHTML($input,false);
    // ^ I thought removing the new line would fix it but didn't
    $tcpdf->Output($output, 'I');
```

Comment: What TCPDF version are you using?

Comment: the latest one: 6.0.064

Comment: And what does `$input` have in it?